# If statement does nothing javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Okay so here's a simple question that I understood but got asked... let's say you have an `if` statement

```
if (window.location.href == 'http://' ||
    window.location.href == 'http://?pg=pgOldMainMenu' ||
    window.location.href == 'http://default.asp#') 

else {}
```

How can you say "if positive do nothing, else load this HTML"?

Comment: if what is positive?

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question?

Comment: yes sorry... Okay so i have these urls... If link is checked and it returns a positive that the browser is on this url i want the script to do nothing.. if it is on any other url i want it to load my html..

Comment: In general you don't want to have an empty `if` block with an `else` block.  It's better to invert the conditional to just use the `if` block by itself.  However, it's not clear what's wrong with your code or what's stopping you from doing what you're trying to do.  If you don't want any code in your `if` block, don't put code in your `if` block.

Comment: How could the location ever match those, they aren't valid URL's ?

Comment: the urls are valid i just didnt put my business website.

Comment: I want my html to load on all pages except these 3 urls.. how can i do this.. Im very limited to what i can edit. I can load a JS and CSS dynamically to delete all content on page and replace with html thats inside the JS and load my css but it does it for specified urls can i use a wildcard or smtg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply like this

```
var href = window.location.href;

if (href == 'http://' ||
    href == 'http://?pg=pgOldMainMenu' ||
    href == 'http://default.asp#') {}   // do nothing
else {
    href = 'url you want to load';
}
```

Comment: for ELSE i want to use every other url... there are about 100 :p.. i cant add them all

Comment: @RajatSharma What do you mean by every other url? This will load only one url. Elaborate yourself in the question first.

Comment: That's what this is doing. In English it would read "If I am on any one of these three sites then do nothing, otherwise do whatever is in the else block". No need to add any more URLs.